# I’m not able to import my pip module after installing it from my CMD

Tags: python, import, cmd, pip, module

I just installed camelcase using the pip command on my cmd.
When I try pip list, the module is present but when I try to import it to my text editor, it tells me that it does not exist.
I installed another module and I was able to import it.

I’ve tried uninstalling and reinstalling it again but it’s not still working.

Answer (score 0):

Which code editor are you using? In my case when I had similar problems with installing packages I tried installing them directly from terminal in my PyCharm app. For me it worked out perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are importing the right class.
`from camelcase import CamelCase`